# Git Delete Remote Branch Without Deleting Local Branch

Tags: git, bitbucket

Simple question but can't find a readily packaged answer for myself. If I delete a remote branch, will git delete my local branch as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, and any actions relying on the remote branch (such as `push` and `pull`) will error out with a message about a missing upstream branch.

`status` will report a message as follows:

> Your branch is based on 'origin/branch', but the upstream is gone.

---

The answer above is accurate to the best of my knowledge - with the caveat that I do not know all implementations of `git`, nor do I know all the command line tools or GUIs that use it.

Answer (score 4):

In case you want to delete remote and still continue working on local branch.
You can try with below commands -

1. Delete the remote branch -

> `git branch -rd origin/<branch-name>`

2. Update remote repo with deleted branch to remove from server -

> ```
> `git push origin :<branch-name>`
> ```

3. Start working on your branch -

> `git checkout <branch-name>`

4. To remove warning of `upstream is gone` -

> ```
> `git branch --unset-upstream`
> ```

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not delete your local branch if you delete the remote branch. You won't be able to push your local changes on this branch to the remote repository though, until and unless you create this branch again on remote server or you push using `git push --set-upstream origin <branch-name>`